# Express route being "skipped" for next route

Tags: node.js, express

My router setup is as follows:

app.js

```
global.express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(require('./server/routes/index'));
```

index.js

```
var router = express.Router();
router.use('/', require('./home.js'));
router.use('/inviteParticipants', require('./invite.js'));
module.exports = router;
```

invite.js

```
var router = express.Router();
router.use('/route1', require('./route1.js'));
router.use('/route2', require('./route2.js'));
module.exports = router;
```

route1.js

```
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/:key', function(req, res, next) {
  // ..code
}
module.exports = router;
```

route2.js

```
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/:key', function(req, res, next) {
  // ..code
}
module.exports = router;
```

home.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // code
}
```

When making a request to both `/inviteParticipants/route1` and `inviteParticipants/route2`, `/route2` seems to catch both requests.

However, if I comment out `router.use('/route2',...)` in invite.js, `/route1` will catch it's corresponding route, and the route originally intended for route `route2` will simply return a 404.

So, `route1` works as intended, but when `route2` is available, it seems to catch the `route1` request instead. `route1` does not use a `next()` call, if that matters. I have double checked the routes being requested and the route going to `route1` is correct.

What could I be doing wrong here to be "skipping" `route1`?

Comment: Well, without seeing all the definitions of routers and how each one is created and hooked into Express, I can't really follow what is what.  Just not enough code shown for me to play.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok I added more code in there. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Can't reproduce with the code you're posting.

Comment: I agree.  I don't see any way to reproduce what you're reporting with only the code you've shown.

Comment: That is my exact routing code. What more is needed?

Comment: At least two people cannot reproduce your problem with the code that you posted. Although I doubt it's caused by `home.js`, add (the gist of) its contents too.

Comment: @robertklep I posted the home.js route. What does this mean: "At least two people cannot reproduce your problem with the code that you posted"?

Comment: @skwny it means that I actually tried running the code you posted, and it works just fine. And jfriend00 also concludes that the code you posted cannot lead to the error you're getting. My guess is that you're leaving something out that you think is not relevant, but may actually be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @robertklep can you share this code? Thanks.

Comment: @skwny https://github.com/robertklep/so-43474609

Answer (score 0):

Every time you write

```
var router = express.Router();
```

you are overwriting the previously declared router. You're only really exporting the last declared router in your file. Rename them to

```
var routeOne = express.Router();
```

if you need to export multiple routers.

Comment: Those are separate files, not one file. I'll pull out the filenames to make it more clear.